# Can't initialize conda on powershell: CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda init'

Tags: python, powershell, conda

I'm trying to set up a conda environment (version 4.5.4) in my work computer (important because i don't have admin privileges), to write python scripts in VSCode.
(I'm sorry if I'm not descriptive enough but since is my work computer i can't really take screenshots as i would like)

I have a problem where I can't  activate virtual environments from the powershell.
I am able to create environments through conda create --name "coolname", with no problem. But when I do conda activate "coolname" it doesn't do anything, by checking with conda env list it turns out the base is still activated.

I have added conda to the environment path in windows. I have added both the C:\users\Anaconda3_64 and C:\users\Anaconda3_64\Scripts at first. PRoblem then was that conda activate gave an error CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run... where it told me to run some bash, which i don't have in my PC. Then I added C:\users\Anaconda3_64\Library\bin, but it only works when it is at the top of the path and now I have my current problem.
Now, aside from that, since I can actually create conda envs I can work with VSCode selecting the right interpreter.

I have already tried:

- Triple checked the right links are in the PATH, i used where conda inside anaconda prompt
- Checking execution policy: it is unrestricted.
- "conda init" or "conda init powershell" seems to work for most people, but it doesnt work for me, as it returns a No command: command innit (I have tried to look for this error online, but I literally haven't seen a single example of this)

Some characteristics of my version:

- Conda version 4.5.4
- It is from an anaconda installation
- Windows 10
- Execution policy unrestricted
- The base environment is read only
- There is no condabin folder (idk why, in my personal PC there is one)
- I don't think we have bash and can't install any third party software

In summary:

1. I can always create environments and conda commands seem to work (conda env list, info, etc)
2. When PATH has Anaconda and Anaconda/Scripts (NOT anaconda/library/bin)

- CMD: commandnotfound error, shell not properly configured when trying to activate an environment
- powershell: commandnotfound error, shell not properly configured when trying to activate an environment
- CMD in VSCode: no errors, can activate any environment
- powershell in VSCode: commandnotfound error, shell not properly configured when trying to activate an environment

3. When PATH has Anaconda, Anaconda/Scripts and Anaconda/library/bin (this one has to be at the top otherwise is the same situation as before)

- CMD: no errors, can activate any environment
- powershell: no errors when trying to activate, but it never activates the right environment, it's always the base one
- CMD in VSCode: no errors, can activate any environment
- powershell in VSCode: no errors when trying to activate, but it never activates the right environment, it's always the base one

PD: this commandnotfounderror is this one:

````
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
 If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with 
   $ echo ". C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc 
or, for all users, enable conda with 
$ sudo ln -s C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh 
The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT put conda's base (root) environment on PATH. 
To do so, run $ conda activate in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run 
$ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc 
Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in your ~/.bashrc file. 
You should manually remove the line that looks like
 export PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64/bin:$PATH" 
^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^```
````